# Has anyone used beta profiling module

Tags: 7, debugging

For most of my projects i am using [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module. Recently i looked at other module Profiling - it also provide integration with views and Panels. I was thinking to use this, as mentioned [here](http://drupal.org/project/profiling) it is stable but still lacks the Views and Panels support. So not sure i should use it or not (i am using views and panels).

Is there anybody who used this module and found it working (without bugs) ?

OR

You would recommend other module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used profiling 7.x-1.0-alpha1, as it was alpha release there were some issues. I hope those have been fixed in the beta release, so maybe you can use it. I would recommend not to use the beta version either; it can break anything.

However, if you are willing to learn how to use this module, just use it; it is not too risky.

Comment: Thanks bee for your quick response. Actually i was not sure how much it could break other functionality. Defiantly I am not going to use on production environment until i am not happy with it on my dev server. I will test it on my local machine.

Comment: i was curious is there any other better module for profiling with panels

Comment: @innocent there are other modules but sorry, i have not used on commercial level. you need to do some research -:)